# Building ActiveMQ-CPP with MinGW?

Tags: windows, mingw, activemq-cpp

I have an upcoming Qt project that requires the use of ActiveMQ-CPP libraries. From my study so far, it seems ActiveMQ-CPP only supports MSVC on Windows. I'd prefer sticking with MinGW since it's a cross-platform project and all other platforms use gcc.

Is there any guide or just outright yes or no on making ActiveMQ-CPP working with MinGW?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActiveMQ-CPP project doesn't support builds on Windows using Cygwin or MinGW tools.  You can of course go it own your own and try to mod the configure.ac script to setup the build flags correctly to make it work.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably as close as an outright no for an answer. :) I really don't have time to tweak it to make it work with MinGW. I guess I will have to use MSVC on Windows build.

Comment: Its not really a no, since the code does build and run on Linux its not to far from working on MinGW.  In the open source world it up to folks to help out and contribute in order to add functionality like this, as long as no one contributes it will remain unsupported on some platforms.